# Create a CGPath around an object surrounded by transparency

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am preparing an ipad app using Sprite Kit, and I need some image processing.

I have a PNG image containing a unique object at the center of it.
Here on my example it's an 'heart'
My goal is to process image to create a CGPath around it (I draw a line to display what I should get)

What is the best algorithm to attack this issue ?
[image]

PS: I already managed to extract the alpha channel from the UIImage.

PS2 : In other words, I need to do what the software Physics Editor is doing : auto trace collision shape
[image]
<sub>(source: [codeandweb.com](https://cdn.codeandweb.com/img/physicseditor/features.jpg))</sub>

Comment: The algorithm would be taking a point that was not transparent (randomly until found) and then moving out 1px by 1px until you move to a transparent pixel. There you have the starting point. Then you select one of the 8 neighbor pixels that are transparent and next to a non-transparent pixels, and not visited yet. You keep doing this and you will have all the surrounding pixels. You can take only one every n pixels to have a simpler shape.

Comment: If you only need this path for a physicsBody then there is a method for that SKPhysicsBody(texture: size:)

Comment: @Okapi No, it's not for physicsBody it's more for touch detection since I have several layers stacked together.